# Laravel. Update two tables at one POST method

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this code right there, this code is working fine and data is successfully stored to table "reports". But I also want to update Users table and their field Credits also. How can I do this in this function ? I also have the relationship between these two tables "reports" and "users".

```
    public function giveCredits($id)
{
    $report = Report::where('id', $id)->first();
    $report->credits += Input::get('credits');
    $report->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Users Table

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->integer('credits');
    $table->enum('role', ['user', 'admin'])->default('user');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Reports table

```
    Schema::create('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->integer('credits');
```

Comment: Can you give us the structure of the tables user and report pls ?

Comment: @SofieneDjebali Yeah, I've updated my post

Comment: How have you set the relation in your model ?

Comment: @SofieneDjebali Yes :)

Comment: Then if the relation are set properly and the report record correctly set to a user, u do not have nothing to do, the user should has been updated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the logic to update the user (assuming you have a relationship method called `user`):

```
public function giveCredits($id)
{
    $report = Report::where('id', $id)->first();
    $report->credits += Input::get('credits');

    // if the report has a user, update it
    if ($report->user) {
        $report->user->credits += Input::get('credits');
        $report->user->save();
    }

    $report->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I'm back to programming so sometimes I forget these simple things. Thanks once again!